# How to show time day difference compared to current date?

Tags: ios, swift, datetime, swift3

I have a createdAt timestamp. That createdAt timestamp will be compared to current date (`Date()`).

Let's say currentDate is 1 august 2018. If the createdAt was 28 july 2018, then just show 28 July 2018. But if the createdAt date is the same day (1 august 2018), then just show 2 m ago, 5h 38m ago, 15s ago something like that, like this one:

[image]

I have tried to use the code below but the result is inconsistent. If the day is different but the code below still shows 5h 16m.

```
func calculateTimeDifference() -> String? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

    guard let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: dateTimeString) else {
        return nil
    }

    let date2 = Date()

    let components : Set<Calendar.Component> = [.second, .minute, .hour, .day, .month, .year]
    let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: date1, to: date2)

    var dateTimeDifferenceString = ""

    var secondDifference = ""
    var minuteDifference = ""
    var hourDifference = ""
    var dayDifference = ""

    if difference.second! < 0 {
        secondDifference = "0"
    } else {
        secondDifference = String(difference.second!)
    }

    if difference.minute! < 0 {
        minuteDifference = "0"
    } else {
        minuteDifference = String(difference.minute!)
    }

    if difference.hour! < 0 {
        hourDifference = "0"
    } else {
        hourDifference = String(difference.hour!)
    }

    if difference.day! < 0 {
        dayDifference = "0"
    } else{
        dayDifference = String(difference.day!)
    }


    if difference.minute! == 0 {
        dateTimeDifferenceString = "\(secondDifference)s"
    } else if difference.hour == 0 {
        dateTimeDifferenceString = "\(minuteDifference)m"
    } else if difference.day == 0 {
        dateTimeDifferenceString = "\(hourDifference)h \(minuteDifference)m"
    } else if  difference.day! > 0 {
        dateTimeDifferenceString = "different day \(dayDifference)"
    }

    return dateTimeDifferenceString
}
```

Could you please share your code?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd use a `DateComponentsFormatter`, it's a safer bet then trying to perform mathematical operations on time, which is never a good idea

```
let duration = Date().timeIntervalSince(date1)
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .abbreviated
formatter.allowedUnits = [ .day, .hour, .minute, .second]

let durationFormat = formatter.string(from: duration)
```

Have a look at [Formatting a Duration with NSDateComponentsFormatter](https://crunchybagel.com/formatting-a-duration-with-nsdatecomponentsformatter/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

i think, the first problem is in here:

```
let components : Set<Calendar.Component> = [.second, .minute, .hour, .day, .month, .year]
```

Your maximum information is Day, but you get components until Year. This will result: `2018-07-01 to 2018-08-01 => year=0, month=1, day=0`

If you need only Day component at maximum, set the components to maximum Day like below.

```
let components : Set<Calendar.Component> = [.second, .minute, .hour, .day]
```

Will result: `2018-07-01 to 2018-08-01 => year=nil, month=nil, day=31`

Second problem is your logic to determine `dateTimeDifferenceString`. I think it should be like this.

```
func calculateTimeDifference() -> String? {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

    guard let date1 = dateFormatter.date(from: dateTimeString) else {
        return nil
    }

    let date2 = Date()

    let components : Set<Calendar.Component> = [.second, .minute, .hour, .day]
    let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents(components, from: date1, to: date2)

    var dateTimeDifferenceString = ""

    if difference.day! > 0 {
        dateTimeDifferenceString = "different day \(difference.day!)"
    } else if difference.hour! > 0 {
        dateTimeDifferenceString = "\(difference.hour!)h \(difference.minute!)m"
    } else if difference.minute! > 0 {
        dateTimeDifferenceString = "\(difference.minute!)m"
    } else {
        dateTimeDifferenceString = "\(difference.second!)s"
    }

    return dateTimeDifferenceString
}
```